# Iphone SDK: Tableview tutorials?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've already done plenty of game-apps and music-apps. However, none of those envolved any use of tableviews. Recently i got a good idea for an app based on tableviews. My problem is: I have 0 tableview knowledge!

If you know some good tableview tutorials, please tell me :). I want to learn everything about tableviews. I also want to know how to use detail-text of a tablecell and how to customize a cell.

Tnanks in advance!

Comment: If you have experience in iOS development, y dont you be aware of apple documentation?

Comment: Yeah... i read some of it never got how to use it though :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return 100;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return arr_finallistoffb.count;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WhispersCell";
        WhispersCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[WhispersCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        }

                    int cellheight;
            NSString *str_question=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            UIFont *font_question = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Medium" size:14.0];
            CGSize size12312 = [(str_question ? str_question : @"") sizeWithFont:font_question constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(260.0f, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            cellheight=size12312.height+35;
            NSString *str_answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[arr_Answer_filters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Medium" size:14.0];
            CGSize size = [(str_answer ? str_answer : @"") sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(260.0f, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            cellheight=cellheight+size.height+20;

        if ([[[arr_finallistoffb objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"int_id"] isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:PREF_USER_ID]])
        {
            cell.btn_CommentIcon.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
            cell.plusbtnOutlet.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.btn_CommentIcon.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            cell.plusbtnOutlet.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

        }

        cell.img_users.layer.borderWidth=3.0;
        cell.img_users.layer.cornerRadius=cell.img_users.frame.size.height/2;
        cell.lbl_UserName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arr_finallistoffb objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"var_username"]];
        [cell.img_users.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:(12.0/255.0) green:(14.0/255.0) blue:(41.0/255.0) alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
        cell.img_users.layer.masksToBounds=YES;


        [cell.img_users setImageWithURL:[APPDELEGATE getURLForMediumSizeImage:[[arr_finallistoffb objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"var_img"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logoinofficiel"] usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];


        cell.plusbtnOutlet.tag=indexPath.row;
        [cell.plusbtnOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_add_culturellis:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        if ([[[arr_finallistoffb objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"is_follower"]integerValue]==1)
        {
            [cell.plusbtnOutlet setSelected:YES];

        }
        else{

            [cell.plusbtnOutlet setSelected:NO];
        }
        [cell.button_userselection addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_User_culturellis:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Overview_Register"])
    {
        WDRegisterViewController *obj=(WDRegisterViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        obj.str_Title=@"Edit Profile";
        obj.isRegister=NO;
    }
}

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Overview_Measure" sender:nil];



    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    WDPeekViewController *Peek = (WDPeekViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WDPeekViewController"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];

        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
    }
```